# Adding a second ExpressRoute connection to an Azure virtual network with networkconfig.xml

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

We are trying to add a second ExpressRoute connection to a vNet in an Azure subscription. We have already successfully completed the connection to our first ExpressRoute (we are using the Exchange Provider method) using a combination of the virtual network GUI and powershell cmdlet tools.

However... the GUI only supports adding one site-to-site VPN via ExpressRoute.

The method for adding a secondary site-to-site connection is to export the network configuration (via the Azure portal) and edit the resulting NetworkConfig.xml file - and then re-import this via the portal.

All good, in theory.

The NetworkConfig.xml file exported from the gui:

```
<Gateway>
<ConnectionsToLocalNetwork>
 <LocalNetworkSiteRef name="XXXX">
  <Connection type="Dedicated" />
 </LocalNetworkSiteRef>
</ConnectionsToLocalNetwork>
</Gateway>
```

In conjunction with MS Support (with whom we are still engaged), we determined the following should work:

```
<Gateway>
<ConnectionsToLocalNetwork>
 <LocalNetworkSiteRef name="XXXX">
  <Connection type="Dedicated" />
 </LocalNetworkSiteRef>
 <LocalNetworkSiteRef name="YYYY">
  <Connection type="Dedicated" />
 </LocalNetworkSiteRef>
</ConnectionsToLocalNetwork>
</Gateway>
```

However, attempting to import this generates the following error message:

> "The gateway in virtual network site XXX-XXX-XX referenced multiple local
> network sites and uses a connection type different than 'IPsec' for at
> least one of the connections. If a gateway references more than one local
> network site, the connection type to all local network sites must be
> 'IPsec'. 'IPsec' is the default connection type."

This appears to suggest multiple ExpressRoute connections on a single vNet are not supported, which would be contrary to the MS FAQ here:

> Can I have one virtual network connected to more than one ExpressRoute
> circuit?
>
> Yes. You can link a single virtual network with up to 4 ExpressRoute
> circuits. All ExpressRoute circuits must be in the same continent. They
> can be ordered through different service providers and in different
> locations.

(from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/expressroute-coexist/)

Does anyone have any idea how we should proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this task using APIs. You can link up to 4 ExpressRoute circuits to a virtual network. You can do this by linking the same vnet to multiple circuits. Below is a sample

```
new-azurededicatedcircuitlink -servicekey <skey1> -vnetname <vnet>
new-azurededicatedcircuitlink -servicekey <skey2> -vnetname <vnet>
```

In the above example skey 1 and skey 2 represent different circuits.